# Ui-Router - Angularjs getting a simple loading screen using multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working to implement a fullscreen loading page that will show when first loading the app. Basicaly I am trying to accomplish something simple like this (Initial loading page): http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/

For this I had the idea to use UI-Router (so i can re-use during heavy requests). So I tried the following but dosent seem to working no matter how I aproach this.

App config:

```
Main_App.config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    var Loading = {
        abstract: true,
        name: 'Loading',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: "Pages/Loading.html"
    }

    var Home = {
        name: 'Home',
        url: '/Home',
        templateUrl: "Pages/Home.html"
    }


      $stateProvider.state(Loading);
      $stateProvider.state(Home);

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="Main_App">

    <ui-view name="Loading" ></ui-view> //Get a blank page
    <div ui-view="Loading"></div> //Get a blank page

    <div> 
        <div>
            <div>
                 <ui-view></ui-view> //loading page shows up here if i remove abstract.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Would anyone have any idea what im missing?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are using abstract the way it is intended.

> https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#abstract

In my opinion,for your use case loading need not be an abstract state. it can be a normal state which will make necessary API request to fetch data to properly bootstrap your application and having done this will transition the state to /home which is the actual starting point of you're application.

Hope this points you in the right direction.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I tried the normal state and as shown in the example its not working if i try <ui-view name="Loading" ></ui-view> or <div ui-view="Loading"></div>.

Comment: With the name attribute what you are trying to do is called named views, more information here [UI-router Multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)